Trying to recreate a Bifurcation diagram from a paper with python
I am currently trying to recreate a bifurcation diagram from the following paper: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0011238#ack
This is the bifurcation diagram I am trying to recreate:

And these are the differential equations supplied for the system:

I've been trying to plot the nullclines of each equation to eventually plot the points where they intersect for different values of s4 (the bifurcation parameter they chose). I cant help but feel like I am using the wrong equations, also my attempts to plot the nullclines that might indicate any semblance of the bifurcation diagram has not been working,
I was wondering if I am on the right track with using those equations and my fault is in the code, or should perhaps be looking to plot the nullclines of the synthesis rate of Nanog against the degradation rate of nanog, and then do that with multiple values of s4?
This is my code, that I've been trying:
def os_nullcline(os):
    return (u * (((s1 * os**v) / ((k1 + os**v) * do)) * ((s2 * os**v) / ((k2 + os**v) * ds))))/dos


def n_nullcline(n, os):
    return (((s4 * n**b) / (k4 + n**b)) + ((s3 * os**v) / (k3 + os**v)) + np.random.normal(0, sigma) * n)/dn


# Defining values for u and v
npts = 100
os_values = np.linspace(0, 4000, npts)
n_values = np.linspace(0, 4000, npts)

# Calculating the nullcline value
os_null = os_nullcline(os_values)
n_null = n_nullcline(n_values, os_values)

# Plotting nullclines
plt.plot(os_values, os_null, label='os nullcline', color='blue')
plt.plot(n_null, n_values, label='n nullcline', color='red')

Should I be looking at different equation? The paper doesn't supply alternate equations. I have been considering plotting the nullclines of the synthesis of nanog and the degredation of nanog, as when they intersect the levels should be at a steady state, so I tries this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_nullclines(k4, b, s4, k3, s3, dn, v):
    n_values = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    os_values = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)


    # Nullcline equation 1
    nullcline1 = (k4 + n_values**b) * (s4 * n_values**b) + (k3 + os_values**v) * (s3 * os_values**v)                             

    # Nullcline equation 2
    nullcline2 = dn * n_values

    # Plotting nullclines
    plt.plot(n_values, nullcline1, label='Nullcline 1', color='blue')
    plt.plot(n_values, nullcline2, label='Nullcline 2', color='red')

    plt.xlabel('n')
    plt.ylabel('Expression level')
    plt.title('Nullclines of the given equations')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

# Example usage
plot_nullclines(k4=10, b=2, s4=14, k3=10, s3=0.1, dn=1, v=1)

But I only get this graph which cant be right. Where am I going wrong?


A bifurcation diagram shows the locations of the stable and unstable equilibria in dependence of the parameter.
The situation here is essentially one-dimensional as the first equation does not depend on [N], so that its non-zero stable equilibrium is a constant. So it needs to be computed exactly once. Note that it may not exist if the parameters are unsuitable.
In the second equation lose the random term, you are not simulating the SDE here. After that, as s4 occurs linearly, you can compute the curve more easily by isolating s4 and compute the graph as a function of [N].
As post-processing compute from the function table the local minima and maxima of s4 to give the segments the correct dash style.

Hi, thank you so much for your answer. I am very new to both python and differential equations. Could I clarify that I can create the bifurcation diagram by isolating s4as so, 's4 = (dn * n *(k4 + nb))/nb - (s3 osv *(k4 + nb))/((n**b)(k3+os**v))' and calculating s4 for different values of n and plot the corresponding values to get the curve in the bifurcation diagram? I confused how this would work for the sections that have 3 or two values of [n] for certain values of s4, is that what youre refering to with the local minima and maxima of s4?

The only example of creating a bifurcation diagram I've been given in my lectures was to, create multiple plots of the nullclines for different values of s4, and to then plot the values of n where the nullclines intersect against the values of s4. I've tried plotting the nullclines of the transcription rate of N and the degredation rate of N, as the intersections will show the values of N where the system is in steady state, I used this code:
plt.plot(p, ((s4 * pb) / (k4 + pb))/dn+ ((s3 * osv) / (k3 + osv))/dn, 'b')
plt.plot(p, dp*p, 'r')
does this make any sense?
